# How to find character arry location of individual elements in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char first_name[20] {};
    cout << "Enter Your First Name : ";
    cin >> first_name;
    cout << "Hi "<< &first_name <<", Welcome to C++ Programming.";
    return 0;
}
```

if I write `&first_name` it is giving the memory location of first element correctly, but unable to find location of other elements (eg. `&first_name[0]` etc.)

Comment: `&first_name[0]` might not be working because `ostream` has a separate `<<` for `char *` specifically. Try `static_cast<void *>(&first_name[0])`. (Also, don't spam tag. I don't see any need to include a version here but if you need to, only include one. And I don't even see any C++/CLI here).

Comment: Why not simply `for (int i = 0; first_name[i]; i++) std::cout << (char)first_name[i] << '\n';` to output each letter in `first_name` separately? Also see [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696)

Comment: Hello Sir, actually my concern is to find the memory location of each element,.....i know that using namespace std is not better way of approaching,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so @mnhaouas answer explained why it does not work but there are ways around it.

First, old and dirty `C` style, which should be avoided for production code.

```
std::cout << (void *) &first_name[4] << "\n";
```

Again this should be used for debugging or playing around. `C++` is way stricter about converting pointers, but this is still possible

Other and better way to do it is:

```
cout << "Hi "<< std::static_cast<void*> (&first_name[3]) << "\n";
```

Again it is not recommended to use first one.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the c++ string instead

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string first_name;
    cout << "Enter Your First Name : ";
    cin >> first_name;
    cout << "Hi "<< first_name.c_str() <<", Welcome to C++ Programming.";
    return 0;
}
```

Enter Your First Name : Tess
Hi Tess, Welcome to C++ Programming.

Comment: :( sorry this does not answer his question. He is asking for address of a char array element.

Answer (score 0):

Let's explain what happens when you do this:

```
&first_name[0]
```

According to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence):

- We start by fetching the first character in the character array using the subscript operator (we get a `char`)
- We then get the address of that `char` using the address-of operator (we get `char*`)

Now the way things are set up in C++ (`ostream` in particular) is that a `char*` is generally considered a null terminated character array which will be read, one `sizeof(char)` at a time, until a `\0` character is encountered. That's why

```
std::cout << &first_name[1];
```

would print something like `oo` if `foo` was given to stdin (`foo` would look like `foo\0` in memory).

Now if you wanted to get the actual address of each character you could do one of two things:

- Use math (you know that `sizeof(char)` is always 1)
- Cast the `char*` to something else (eg `void*`) so that it is no longer considered a char array by `ostream` or whatever other function that works the same. *To be clear* `char*` is still an address (and is in fact the result you're looking for), it's just displayed differently because `ostream` is overloaded differently for `char*` where it is set up to print whatever is at that location and everything that follows until a null char.

Comment: Simply said if you have `[]` in array and you feed it into `std::iostream`, it is treated as offset from start of an array.